# Find the corresponding nouns or verbs of adjectives and adverbs in an English sentence

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, pos-tagger

My goal is to build an algorithm that given an adjective or adverb within a sentence, indicates the corresponding noun or verb.

For example:

> The boy threw the heavy stone angrily to the window that was very far.

heavy (adj) -> stone

angrily (adv) -> threw

far (adj) -> window

So far I was able to tag Parts of Speech for each word and identify adjectives, nouns, verbs, and adverbs in a given sentence.

1. In Natural Language Processing, is there a terminology for what I'm trying to do?
2. Does a well known algorithm or approach exist for my goal?
3. I wonder if it makes sense to manually train several sentences and build a machine learning model for this? or is it over-engineering the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answers below:

1) Dependency Parsing

2) Yes, several - start with information docs for the Spacy library

3) You would need more than several sentences, easier to use an established library